# Jquery Find, Sort and then Append only specific 'N' numbers child element

Tags: html, jquery, append, parent-child

I am finding child elements from the parent element and sorting them and then adding them on the parent element again:

```
$('#parentElement').find('.childElement').sort(function(a, b) {
    var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-name'));
    var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-name'));
    return (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : 0;
}).appendTo('#parentElement');
```

But I want to append only the first 5 sorted child elements on the parent element. I don't want to append all child elements. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first 5 sorted elements from that collection you can use `.slice()`. Also note that the code can be made more succinct by using `data()` to retrieve the attributes (as this will negate the need to manually call `parseInt()`) and also by combining the original selectors:

```js
$('#parentElement .childElement').remove().sort((a, b) => {
  var contentA = $(a).data('name');
  var contentB = $(b).data('name');
  return (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : 0;
}).slice(0, 5).appendTo('#parentElement');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
  <div class="childElement" data-name="1">1</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="9">9</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="4">4</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="10">10</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="3">3</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="6">6</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="5">5</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="8">8</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="2">2</div>
  <div class="childElement" data-name="7">7</div>
</div>
```